# Is there a way to use an actionCommand in a switch case for a MouseListener?

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, mouselistener

I am working on a navigation panel in a Java swing application.

On the left side I have a navigation menu:

- Order status
- Check reports
- Documentation
- ...
- Go back to main menu

The elements in the navigation are re-configurated `JButtons` that look like lables, are underlined if the mouse hovers over them in order to simulate a hyperlink navigation.

This works fine, but I am using a `MouseListener` on the buttons (**not** an `ActionListener`, since I want to be able to register the mouse hovering over a button, the mouse cursor leaving the button etc.) and `if-statements` to check, which button/label had been clicked.

```
    if (e.getSource() == btn_orderStatus) {
        // Clean everything, then hang in the MAIN navigation panel
        buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
        createLandingPage("centerPanel");
        pageCards.show(centerPanel, "PageOne");
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn_goBack) {
        // Clean everything, then hang in the MAIN navigation panel
        buttonPanel.setVisible(false);
        createLandingPage("empty");
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn_checkReport) {
        ...
    }
```

Since the navigation might be longer later, I wanted to convert the `if-statements` into a `switch-case` and check, which button had been clicked. `Switch-case` mostly works with types like `int`, `String`, so you have to switch over a `String` for example.

When there is an `ActionListener` registered to the re-configured `JButtons`, you can use the `switch-case` like this:

```
switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
    case: "Order status":
          ....
    case: "Check reports":
          ....
}
```

**Notice: The `getActionCommand()` has not been set before! If it is not set, it defaults to the button text!**

But since I am using a `MouseListener` instead of an `ActionListener`, there is no `e.getActionCommand()`!

The alternative is getting the source and casting it into a `JButton`, which works, but might be longer and less elegant than it could be:

```
switch(((JButton) e.getSource.getText())){...
```

So is there a way for a `MouseListener-switch` to use something similar to the `e.getActionCommand()`? Or is the cast-approach already acceptable?

**EDIT:** Here is a GIF of my navigation, so it's easier to understand, why I want to use buttons.

[image: My navigation]

But to be clear: My question is **not** about the visuals, but instead if there is a way to write the line

```
switch(((JButton) e.getSource.getText())){...
```

shorter / more elegant by using something similar to `e.getActionComman()`, which does not exist in a `MouseListener`.

**EDIT2:**

This is how I change my `JButtons` to look like `JLabels`:

```
for (JButton jButton : navigationButtonSecondList) {
    jButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
    jButton.setBorderPainted(true);
    jButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    jButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jButton.addMouseListener(this);
    jButton.setEnabled(false);
    jButton.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

With this code the re-worked `JButtons` are bolded and underlined. I've also tried to work with `<html><u>buttontext</u></html>`, but somehow I was unable to de-underline the text correctly. So I've used the approach shown here:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // Makes the text in the labels / JButtons bold and "pop out", so the
    // user sees, which label / JButton they are hovering over
    JButton buttonSourceHelper = ((JButton) e.getSource());
    buttonSourceHelper.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    // This is used to underline the labels (JButtons) in order to make them
    // look like hyperlinks
    Font font = buttonSourceHelper.getFont();
    Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    buttonSourceHelper.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
}
```

When the mouse exits the `JButton`, I simply put the font back to size 12 and `PLAIN`:

```
buttonHelper.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: *"..the buttons (not an ActionListener, since I want to be able to register the mouse hovering over a button"* ..why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: When the mouse hovers over a button/label the font becomes bold and underlined, if the mouse leaves the button/label the font becomes plain and not underlined again. Also I am not against using a different approach, I was just curious if there is a way to implement what I've described in my question.

Comment: That could be achieved by writing the text to images, and using them as icons for (normal) icon, hover icon, pressed icon etc. As an aside, turning text **bold** will typically make it wider, which in turn might change the positions of components. If I were making icons of the text, I would do the bold type first, and make all icons the same size as that one.

Comment: @hamena314 I am still unsure why you are using mouseListener. But you can still add ActionListener to your buttons even if you already added the mouseListener. Wouldn't that solve your problem? Apart from that, there are a few other ways..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Interesting idea, altough I have to admit, that I am not yet seeing the advantage of using icons instead of using re-configured buttons, that look like `JLabels`. The buttons will be accessible by the keyboard, while the icons wont iirc? And yes, making the text bold makes the text using more space, but since the navigation panel has quite some space, this is not a problem. On the contrary, the user gets a good usability feedback on which element he exactly is hovering.

Comment: @user3437460: I have to be able to see if the mouse cursor is hovering over a component and then change the component. As far as I understand the `ActionListener` is only for clicking i.e. a element has been chosen by the user, while hovering over it does not determine a decision. Adding a an `ActionListener` might indeed be helpful, I will think about this, thank you!

Comment: Most L&Fs already have a visual indication for hovering over buttons. Are you creating your own L&F? Do you want to change the default behavior?

Comment: @user1803551: No, I do not want to create my own Look and Feel (L&F?). I just want to create a webpage like navigation. I have added a GIF to show what I mean. But a remark: My question is **not** about the visuals, but if there is a way to write the line `switch(((JButton) e.getSource.getText())){...` shorter / more elegant by using something similar to the `e.getActionCommand()` which does not exist in a `MouseListener`.

Comment: I understand. My point is that the "on hover" effects supplied by look and feels are coded in the UI delegate of the button. If you want to have your own effect, then the correct way to do it is through the UI delegate (you also seem to change a lot of the button visuals, so I recommend this). If you don't want to do this then I can write an answer with a couple of options, but I can't guarantee you will prefer them over what you have currently.

Comment: @user1803551: Thanks for the kind offer! You are correct, I do change the `JButtons` quite a bit to make them look like `JLabels`, I have added the code for that. If I can make this better I would like to see how. But I have to ask, is there no **lazier** way to get the `JButton` in the `switch-statement` than to use casting: `((JButton) e.getSource.getText())`?

Comment: `ActionListener`: It depends, are the buttons doing the same thing (all open some page)? You don't want to lump different behavior into the same listener. `MouseListener`: Also depends on what you want to do. You can use `getComponent` which is a bit more specific than `getSource`. I suggest you post what you want to achieve more than what you are trying to do right now. I suspect a design problem.

Comment: @user1803551: I am not sure, if we have a miscommunication here? My design is okay, everything works as it should. Nothing is broken / needs to be fixed. I just want to know, if there is a smarter way to write `((JButton) e.getSource.getText()` or if it is okay to cast into a `JButton` and that's it. But maybe I understand something wrong?

Comment: As I said, `getComponent` could be enough depending on what you actually want to do with the button. For example, setting the font can work on a `Component` and you don't need to cast.

Comment: @user1803551: I want to underline the text in the button, if the mouse hovers over it. I think, bolding the text is not necessary. I've edited the code in, that underlines the text.

Comment: Then with your current design you can't do much better than `getSource`. Your other option is to send the button as a constructor argument to the listener, keep it there as a field, and then you don't need the cast. I still think that the design approach can be improved, but it's out of the scope of what you're asking.

Comment: @user1803551: I have to agree that my design might not be the best, since I am still learning. Might I ask for some hints on what I should change / what is especially wrong, so that I can open another question and improve my approach? Also I appreciate your patience, thank you!

Comment: You will need to explain what you want to do achieve along with an MCVE of what you have. That includes the functionality (listeners) and visuals of the buttons. I would think that you will need to write your own UI delegate.